# C# Comparing two strings, one with unique indenifiers

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, compare, string-comparison

First of all I'd like to mention that I'm new to programming and this sight so I'm still an infant in this world, however, I have a problem.

I have to make code that can compare two strings but the second string (from a file) will have unique identifiers within it. For example:

**first string:**

```
I have 10 cats and their fur is #000000
```

**Second string from a file:**

```
I have <d> cats and their fur is <h>
```

Although I probably don't need to explain, 'd' is for numbers or decimal and 'h' for hex. There are also 's' and 'a' associated to ASCII.

What's supposed to happen is that the first string can have any different number which can be of different length and/or Hex when the data comes in but the rest of the message stays the same, E.G.

```
I have 1500 cats and their fur is #000000
```

the code will still match the two strings as True matches as it'll effectively ignore anything that is an int and hex. (this identifiers are User defined so they can be anywhere in any string).

The end game is that if it finds a relative match the code will change the colour of the text in the app among other things. it's basically to highlight errors in a log file.

I've searched High an low on Stackflow and looked into Regex and string comparisons. I'm currently going to make a start on the code, however, would like some input/help.

**Obviously** I'm not asking for something to be written for me, just to be pointed in the right direction so I can learn.

Many thanks in advance! And apologies if there is a similar post out there, but alas I couldn't find it if there is.

Comment: you need to compare strings without the numbers?

Comment: No, the second string is effectively a mask for the first once diffined it never changes but the first string will but only at the specified points (the identifiers). 
So it'll 'ignore' anything that is a number (at that point until) until it it isn't a number in the first string because the mask string (string 2) has that d identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly I think I would solve this by replacing the `<d>` etc. by a RegEx expression. Then use that RegEx to replace the values by an empty string. That way you can compare them without the values.

Hope that makes sense. I didn't include any code because you asked for just some directions.

Comment: Yes! I've just been reading up on CaptureCollection. [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966(v=vs.80).aspx

I think this may do the trick. Many thanks for the feedback @Robert Messa and assuring me that I'm not going insane and in the wrong direction.